# ember-cordova android workflow on linux

Tags: cordova, ember.js

I've installed cordova and android-studio on my system (ubuntu 16.04) and added ember-cordova to my app.

I've run

```
ember cordova:platform add android
ember cordova:build --platform=android
```

and got a succesfull build.
but now how can I run the app?

I've tried

```
ember cordova:open
```

but it complains about a .project file that I don't know:

```
File: /bin/sh
Command failed: xdg-open /home/ck/repositories/test/web-app/ember-cordova/cordova/platforms/android/.project
```

doing

```
ember cordova:open --platform=android --application=android-studio
```

opens android studio who also complains about that .project file and then starts the "Scanning files to index..." activity and freezes there...

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to run your app?

- At browser? Just run `ember s`. But before that you have to set `EMBER_CLI_CORDOVA=0`. Have a look [at doc](https://github.com/poetic/ember-cli-cordova/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#developing-the-app).
- At emulator? Run `ember cordova emulate`. Before that you need to create an image for your emulator.
- At your phone? Copy your build (apk) to your phone, give needed permission, then run.

**Note**: I've used [ember-cli-cordova](https://github.com/poetic/ember-cli-cordova/), not [ember-cordova](https://github.com/isleofcode/ember-cordova). ember-cordova was forked from ember-cli-cordova as mentioned [here](https://github.com/poetic/ember-cli-cordova/blob/3e5ed7e4d8a6e8c9210e9f586c6e18e568339617/README.md#ember-cordova) and [here](https://github.com/isleofcode/ember-cordova#credits). I've written this post by **assuming** that *both of them have the same behaviours*.